# 16-Bits BMP Validation

Tags: validation, file-io, vbscript, image-manipulation, bmp

I'm developing a script using VBScript and I need to validate the input file as a 16-Bits BMP.

At the time my script is like this:

```
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFile "C:\16bmp.bmp" , "D:\test.bmp", OverwriteExisting
```

But How can I validate the input file as a 16-Bits BMP?




*PS: Remember that I need this to be compatible with my site and Windows CE(I will develop a program for it using NSBasic).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I got you right (English being my second language), but if you need to check if a file is a 16-bit BMP image (and not verify the actual pixels), you can make use of the Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) scripting objects. Here's an example:

```
Const wiaIDUnknown = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
Const wiaFormatBMP = "{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"

Set oImg = CreateObject("Wia.ImageFile")

On Error Resume Next

oImg.LoadFile("C:\image.bmp")

If oImg.FormatID = wiaIDUnknown Then
  ' The file isn't an image file
Else
  Log.Message "Is BMP: " & (oImg.FormatID = wiaFormatBMP)
  Log.Message "Color depth: " & oImg.PixelDepth
End If
```

This script requires that you have the *wiaaut.dll* library installed and registered on your computer; if you don't have it, you can download it as part of the [WIA SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a332a77a-01b8-4de6-91c2-b7ea32537e29&displaylang=en).

See also [WIA documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630827.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I got this error: `ActiveX component can't create object 'Wia.ImageFile'`, also I forgot to say that this need to be compatible with Windows CE(via NSBasic).

Comment: Most probably you don't have the wiaaut.dll library registered (see note in the end of the answer). I don't know whether Windows CE supports WIA though.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to read the file data and compare it to the [BMP format specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

There are three ways I know of to work with binary files in VBScript:

1. Using the ADODB component. This method is kind of limited. You can find an article about it at [VBScript Read Binary File](http://nerds-central.blogspot.com/2007/01/ok-you-win-vbscript-read-binary-file.html).
2. You could write your own COM component and call it from the script. I did a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=com+component+binary+read) and found some ready-made components that offer this functionality.
3. You could also install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) and use it to identify the BMP. That might be overkill for your purposes though.